# Unable to start receiver com.example.callrecorder.CallReciever: java.lang.RuntimeException: start failed. MEDIA RECORDER ISN'T WORKING PROPERLY

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-manifest, mediarecorder

I am developing an app to record calls. In the Main Activity , I am asking for all the permissions required to record calls. In Broadcast Receiver , I am handling incoming and outgoing calls and recording respectively. But app is showing error which states that media Recorder is not able to start. As far as I have understood , code is working fine before declaring filepath. When I declared filepath , app is crashing on recieving a call. I think there is some issue in definefilepath() or i am calling it wrong time.

**BROADCAST RECIEVER CODE**

class CallReciever : BroadcastReceiver() {

```
private val mediaRecorder = MediaRecorder()
lateinit var filePath : String

override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {

    if(intent?.action == TelephonyManager.ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED){
        val state = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE)
        when(state){
            TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING->{
                //Handle incoming call - start recording
                val incomingNumber = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER)
                callRecorder()
                Log.i("anshi","call recieved and Call Recording is going on")
            }

            TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK->{//perform actions when an outgoing call is answered
                //Handle call answered - store recording
               callRecorder()
                Log.i("anshi","call outgoing and Call Recording is going on")
            }
            TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE->{//perform actions when a call ends.
                //Handle call ended - end recording
                Log.i("anshi","call has ended")
                mediaRecorder.stop()
                mediaRecorder.reset()
                mediaRecorder.release()

            }
        }
    }
}



private fun defineFilePath() {
    val directory = File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "Recordings")
    directory.mkdirs()

    val fileName = "recording_${System.currentTimeMillis()}.mp3"
    filePath = File(directory, fileName).absolutePath
    Log.i("anshi","defined file path")
}

private fun callRecorder() {

    defineFilePath()

    mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_CALL)
    mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4)
    mediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC)
    mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(filePath)

    try {
        // Prepare the MediaRecorder
        mediaRecorder.prepare()

        // Start the recording
        mediaRecorder.start()

    } catch (e: IOException) {
        // Handle any exceptions that occur during recording
    }
}
```

}

[image]

Comment: Please don't post screen shots of stack traces, just include the test in your question. As far as I know call recording is no longer possible on recent Android versions.

Comment: I got an assignment to make a call recording app , how can I do it now?

Answer (score 0):

As @Robert said call recording is problem on recent android versions.

> I got an assignment to make a call recording app , how can I do it now?

Nowadays you can do this on recent android versions with accessibility service. But then you cannot publish your app to play store